# Error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, arrays, numberformatexception

I am trying to input numbers as a `string` and splitting and storing them in a `string` array and then later storing them as integers in `int` array. I have tried quite a few things like `.trim()` or `scanner.skip()` but am unable to solve this issue here.

My Input:

```
4 
1 2 2 2
```

```
 public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arCount = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] ar = new int[arCount];
    String[] arItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < arCount; i++) {
        int arItem = Integer.parseInt(arItems[i].trim());
        ar[i] = arItem;
    }
    scanner.close();
 }
```

The error received is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Hello.main(Hello.java:32)
```

Comment: Integer.parseInt() cannot convert the empty string to an int ... you are gettting empty strings in your input because of multiple spaces ... the split method will generate empty strings in your array if there are two spaces placed adjacent to each other

Comment: Well, I thought about that and was careful with the input. Also, tried the ` scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");` that we usually see on hackerrank in order to skip all the spaces. But, the error still remains for some reason.

Comment: It's not clear what input you are getting..

Comment: I just added what my input is to the question.

Comment: Is that just the example input? Have you tried printing out what is being scanned?

Comment: Or simply check if arItems[i].trim() is not empty then cast to integer and put into array otherwise do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the nextInt() method over and over again (bypassing the use of split totally), like so,

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String []args){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arCount = scanner.nextInt();

    int[] ar = new int[arCount];
    for(int i=0;i<arCount;i++){
        ar[i] = scanner.nextInt();;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));

    scanner.close();
 }
}
```

UPDATE:

In your original program, you are using nextInt() method first, which does not consume the newline character '\n'. So, the next invocation of nextLine() actually consumes the newline character on the same line instead of the line below that which contains the integers for your array. So, for your code to work properly, you can modify it slightly as follows,

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String []args){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arCount = scanner.nextInt(); // doesn't consume \n
    int[] ar = new int[arCount];
    scanner.nextLine(); //consumes \n on same line 
    String line = scanner.nextLine(); // line is the string containing array numbers
    System.out.println(line);
    String[] arItems = line.trim().split(" "); //trim the line first, just in case there are extra spaces somewhere in the input
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arItems));
    for (int i = 0; i < arCount; i++) {
        int arItem = Integer.parseInt(arItems[i].trim());
        ar[i] = arItem;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arItems));
 }
}
```

Comment: This was actually useful! Thanks for this edit. But, if you find out if something can be done to successfully convert the string array while avoiding the above error, please let me know.

Comment: @PremanshuYadav, I updated the answer. You need to have an extra nextLine() invocation for your program to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the exception and skip over bad records.

I would also suggest you split on one or more spaces to prevent empty strings to begin with

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int arCount = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine();
int[] ar = new int[arCount];
String[] arItems = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");

for (int i = 0; i < arCount; i++) {
    try {
        ar[i] = Integer.parseInt(arItems[i].trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.err.println(arItems[i] + " is not an int");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but still not effective. But this was helpful too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try using .trim() after Scanner.nextLine().

```
String[] arItems = scanner.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
```

Comment: This won't work in all cases ... what if there are multiple spaces somewhere in between?